# Make custom column using variables and conditions off another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple query that pulls data from multiple tables with a few conditions

```
select x, step, code, ....,
from 
table 1
inner join table 2
inner join table 3
where
'filters'
order by x, code
```

This gives me a table where two columns with step and code:

| x | step | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0001 |
| 1 | 10 | 0000 |
| 1 | 20 | 0000 |
| 1 | 30 | 0000 |
| 1 | 40 | 0000 |
| 1 | 1000 | 0001 |
| 2 | 0 | 0000 |
| 2 | 10 | 0000 |
| 2 | 20 | 0000 |

As above, the 0 step indicates whether the process failed and the sub-step shows exactly which part. Then when step goes back to 0 it is now a new process.

Is there a way to pull the 0 step value of the code (so in this case it would be "0001") and then use that value as the code until it reaches the next step 0 and update the value?

So the table would now look like this:

| x | step | code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0001 |
| 1 | 10 | 0001 |
| 1 | 20 | 0001 |
| 1 | 30 | 0001 |
| 1 | 40 | 0001 |
| 1 | 1000 | 0001 |
| 2 | 0 | 0000 |
| 2 | 10 | 0000 |
| 2 | 20 | 0000 |

It can be a new column, I just indicated the same one to save time.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Not without a value to order your data on, and your data has no such value.

Comment: The table is ordered so that is always the output. Its ordered by another value and then by step, I can't include the other columns

Comment: *"The table is ordered so that is always the output"* No, it's not; tables are by definition unordered. When you have no `ORDER BY` in your query, then the order of your data is completely arbitrary, and what that arbitrary order is can be different *every* time you run the query, even if that query is a simple `SELECT * FROM dbo.SomeTable;`.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I included it in the question but missed it off

Comment: What is `x`? Include it in your sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You confused code with step in your `ORDER BY` clause. Change this, so as to get a deterministic result with step 0 always being the first step shown for an x.

Use `FIRST_VALUE` to get the code for step 0 per x.

```
select x, step, first_value(code) over (partition by x order by step) as xcode
inner join table 2
inner join table 3
where <filters>
order by x, step;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, sorry for the mislabeling. I understand why the other column is important.